# Bitrise giving issue gradle-runner

Tags: bitrise

i am using the bitrise but when i am creating the PR and build is generated i am facing the issue of the of gradle-wrapper-runner on the bitrise , some test are failing but is this the only reason my build is failing? Just wanted to know as i am using the continuous integration tool for the first time.

```
 > Transform byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.0) with JetifyTransform
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.junit}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.mockito}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${version.asm}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
> Transform kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.60) with JetifyTransform
> Transform kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.60) with IdentityTransform
> Transform byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform spek-api.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.2.1) with JetifyTransform
> Transform spek-api.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.2.1) with IdentityTransform
> Transform spek-junit-platform-engine.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.2.1) with JetifyTransform
> Transform spek-junit-platform-engine.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.2.1) with IdentityTransform
> Transform commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.12) with JetifyTransform
> Transform commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.12) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-kotlin.jar (com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0) with JetifyTransform
> Transform mockito-kotlin.jar (com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-core.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0) with JetifyTransform
> Transform mockito-core.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-inline.jar (org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.9) with JetifyTransform
> Transform mockito-inline.jar (org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.9) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-runner.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.2) with JetifyTransform
> Transform junit-platform-runner.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Transform opentest4j.jar (org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.0.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-commons.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-engine.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-suite-api.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite-api:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-launcher.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Transform objenesis.jar (org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6) with IdentityTransform
> Transform byte-buddy-agent.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.9.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform byte-buddy.jar (net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) with IdentityTransform
> Transform kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.60) with IdentityTransform
> Transform spek-api.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.2.1) with IdentityTransform
> Transform commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.12) with IdentityTransform
> Transform spek-junit-platform-engine.jar (org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.2.1) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-core.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-kotlin.jar (com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0) with IdentityTransform
> Transform mockito-inline.jar (org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.9) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit-platform-runner.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.2) with IdentityTransform
> Task :app:generateDebugUnitTestSources
> Task :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Transform xmlpull.jar (org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform kobjects-j2me.jar (net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform kxml.jar (net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform ksoap2-base.jar (com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.3) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform okio.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform autolink.jar (org.nibor.autolink:autolink:0.6.0) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform flexmark-util.jar (com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-util:0.28.32) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform kotlin-stdlib-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.21) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform kotlinx-coroutines-core-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.0.0) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform beta.aar (com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.10) with AarTransform
> Transform fabric.aar (io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.8) with AarTransform
> Transform answers.aar (com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7) with AarTransform
> Transform crashlytics-core.aar (com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.8) with AarTransform
> Transform jsr305.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider-asf.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider-asf:1.0.0) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform annotations.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform reactive-streams.jar (org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform aws-android-sdk-core.jar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.12.4) with ExtractProGuardRulesTransform
> Transform junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12) with JetifyTransform
> Transform junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12) with IdentityTransform
> Transform junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12) with IdentityTransform
> Transform aws-android-sdk-auth-core.aar (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-core:2.12.1) with AarTransform
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar/eae2df2233241b71b49e719c402fe1f1/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/4bcc2012b84840e19e1e28074284cac908be0295/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.21/f30e4a9897913e53d778f564110bafa1fef46643/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
> Task :app:kaptDebugUnitTestKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar/eae2df2233241b71b49e719c402fe1f1/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/4bcc2012b84840e19e1e28074284cac908be0295/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.21/f30e4a9897913e53d778f564110bafa1fef46643/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
> Task :app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar/eae2df2233241b71b49e719c402fe1f1/jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.2.60.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.21/4bcc2012b84840e19e1e28074284cac908be0295/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
    /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.21/f30e4a9897913e53d778f564110bafa1fef46643/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.21.jar (version 1.3)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/data/remote/verifone/service/PaymentFlowSpec.kt: (21, 9): Variable 'flow' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/data/remote/verifone/service/PaymentFlowSpec.kt: (41, 13): Variable 'a' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/data/remote/verifone/service/PaymentFlowSpec.kt: (45, 17): Variable 'b' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/data/remote/verifone/service/PaymentFlowSpec.kt: (46, 17): Variable 'c' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/di/NetworkModuleSpec.kt: (26, 31): Check for instance is always 'true'
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/di/NetworkModuleSpec.kt: (35, 31): Check for instance is always 'true'
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/domain/user/registration/RegistrationUseCaseSpec.kt: (106, 21): 'when' expression on enum is recommended to be exhaustive, add 'NONE' branch or 'else' branch instead
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/view/dashboard/payment/amount/EnterAmountViewModelSpec.kt: (26, 18): Variable 'boolTestSub' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/view/dashboard/preferences/ContactPreferencesViewModelSpec.kt: (45, 9): Variable 'viewModel' is never used
w: /Users/vagrant/git/app/src/test/java/com/karmarama/edf/view/login/LoginViewModelSpec.kt: (51, 18): Variable 'completabLeTestSub' is never used
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest
> Task :app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /Users/vagrant/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/android.jar/0bcd694fed722651f20435a98a965b0a/android.jar with input /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-28/android.jar
objc[3466]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10d6d84c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10d7a04e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
com.karmarama.edf.view.dashboard.payment.card.details.EnterCardDetailsViewModelSpec > it should validate ExpiryDate FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError
com.karmarama.edf.view.dashboard.payment.card.details.EnterCardDetailsViewModelSpec > it should validate ExpiryDate FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError
com.karmarama.edf.view.dashboard.payment.card.details.EnterCardDetailsViewModelSpec > it should validate ExpiryDate FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError
com.karmarama.edf.view.dashboard.payment.card.details.EnterCardDetailsViewModelSpec > it should emit continue button state FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at EnterCardDetailsViewModelSpec.kt:177
580 tests completed, 4 failed
> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/vagrant/git/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/vagrant/git/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.handleTestFailures(AbstractTestTask.java:612)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.executeTests(AbstractTestTask.java:484)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:603)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 111 more
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6m 32s
42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
Gradle task failed, error: exit status 1
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | gradle-runner@1.8.4 (exit code: 1)                            | 399 sec  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Update available: 1.8.4 -> 1.8.5                                             |
| Issue tracker: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-gradle-runner/issues      |
| Source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-gr
     x | gradle-runner@1.8.4 (exit code: 1)                            | 525 sec  |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Update available: 1.8.4 -> 1.8.5                                             |
| Issue tracker: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-gradle-runner/issues|
| Source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-gradle-runner
```

Comment: Without the complete step log it's impossible to tell what the error is -> the error description should be somewhere above the lines you copy pasted. If you'd need help with finding the issue just contact our support via the onsite chat or email, they'll guide you through the debugging :)

Comment: please provide the email

Comment: https://www.bitrise.io/contact -> `letsconnect@bitrise.io`

Comment: Btw from the update logs it seems you ran unit tests and those failed (`There were failing tests. See the report at: ...`).

Comment: Though there are also `ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'` errors in the log, which seems like a configuration issue. 

To answer your question "some test are failing but is this the only reason my build is failing?" or at least to help some: what happens if you run these tests locally on your Mac/PC? Are the tests failing? Does it fail if you do a new/clean git clone of the repository into a different directory and run the tests there? (sometimes projects reference files which aren't in the repo, so it passes on your Mac/PC as the file is there)